# vicidial lead loading issue with excel files

Tags: excel, vici

As I am new to vicidial facing problem while loading leads file (excel file with different versions).
so anyone can help me out with what are the suitable versions for lead files in excel format.
my vicidial version is 2.8-51 and build 130824-2322

and also when I upload lead files(excel format) with all required fields it shows an error every time - ERROR-the file does not have the required number of fields to process it.but when i upload same file with .CSV format it loads all lead successfully.
can anyone have idea about this what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We use Wombat that has a drag-and-drop interface for data uploading, but if your files are very large you'd be better off pushing them through an API.

Answer (score 0):

Do a "Save As" for your excel file as a Text (MS-DOS) format and upload. And When you want to edit the text file you created do a "open with" excel.

The columns you may want to have in your .xlsx excel file and .txt text file.

```
lead_id entry_date 
modify_date 
status NEW
user VDAD
vendor_lead_code
source_id
list_id  6876
gmt_offset_now  -4
called_since_last_reset Y
phone_code  1
phone_number  4563214667
title   
first_name   John
middle_initial
last_name  Due
address1  34 BN Street
address2  
address3
city  Baltimore
state MD
province
postal_code  80002
country_code
gender
date_of_birth  0000-00-00
alt_phone
email
security_phrase
comments
called_count   1
last_local_call_time
rank  0
owner  
entry_list_id  0
```